# Get value on click from Angular UI Rating Directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Using this Code here: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/drEXVrd90syISrOP1wBf)

How would I write the value on click to the console? It seems as though this will only work in a form submit environment, but I'm hoping I'm wrong.

Note that the rating element is converted into several i elements in a span, and each i has an ng-click applied to it already.

To summarize - When I select a star, spit out the value selected to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since clicking on an icon changes the value of the bound rating variable, you can just `$watch` the change of that scope variable.

eg.

```
$scope.$watch('rate', function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bPmbgiI9ryZWSrn1zOfU?p=preview

Comment: Wow. That seems like something I really should have known about. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 10):

Rating supports [ng-click](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick):

```
<rating value="rate" max="max" readonly="isReadonly" 
    on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" 
    ng-click="setRating()"></rating>
```

In your controller, simply add:

```
$scope.setRating = function() {
    alert($scope.rate);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! In my case I have a loop with collection of rating-controls. So just added a model object as a function parameter to "click" event handler(ng-click="onRatingChanged(competenceItem)). So in function I will have a full object with all properties(property Rate will have an updated value) and will be able to send this object to the server using AJAX call. Could be useful somebody.

Comment: using a click is way much better than doing a watch in the $scope

Comment: For me, this is better than using a watch. With a watch you can call your function more times than you expect